# Set up [Sharp]C language for listings

Tags: listings

Why must I use style work-around to set C# language in listings?

Why 
`\begin{lstlisting}[language=[Sharp]C]`
cannot be processed by LaTeX?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.9}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{redidentifiers}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{orangestrings}{rgb}{0.6,0.3,0}

% Formatting for any language 
\lstset{columns=flexible,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
stringstyle=\color{orangestrings},
identifierstyle=\color{redidentifiers},
showstringspaces=false
}

\lstdefinestyle{CSstyle} {
  language=[Sharp]C
}

\begin{document}

Java
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
// HelloWorld.java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
and C\#
%\begin{lstlisting}[language=[Sharp]C]
\begin{lstlisting}[style=CSstyle]
// Hello1.cs
public class Hello1 {
   public static void Main() {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World");
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}
look similar.

Python looks different.
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
# Hello.py
s = 'Hello, World'
print s 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the option goes up to the first `]` so is `\begin{lstlisting}[language=[Sharp] ` with an unknown language `[Sharp`  try `\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Sharp]C}] ` but not having brackets in the language name would be better

Comment: Page 12 of the manual: “`language=[77]Fortran` does not work inside an optional argument. You must put braces around the value if a value with optional argument is used inside an optional argument. In the case here write `language={[77]Fortran}` to select Fortran 77.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is explained in the manual of `listings`, page 12 (near the end of section 2.3):

> `language=[77]Fortran` does not work inside an optional argument.
>    You must put braces around the value if a value with optional argument is used inside an optional argument. In the case here write `language={[77]Fortran}` to select Fortran 77.

So do

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Sharp]C}]
```